# Fast updating MySQL Table based on NumPy Array

Tags: python, mysql, numpy, sql-update, mysql-python

Good morning everbody,

I hope you are all well and that you are looking forward to a great weekend!

I've a 2D numpy array containing 2 cols and approximatly 6000 rows [col1 = name = identifiert for where-clause ; col2 = value for column val]:
`x = np.array([['a', '2'], ['b', '2'] , ['c', '1']])`

```
[['a' '2']
 ['b' '2']
 ['c' '1']]
```

Now I need to write those values as an update into an Mysql-table. Currently I'm using a for loop runding through the array and creating sql-querys for each entry
`Update [test_table] SET value = 'val' WHERE Name = 'name'`
which might be acceptable for small amounts of data but is awfully slow for hugh datasets.

Is there anyway to speed this up or idealy to directly use the numpy array for the update?

Answer (score 1):

This is what `executemany` is for:

```
cur.executemany( "UPDATE test_table SET value=? WHERE Name=?", x )
```

Now, that assumes "value" is first and "name" is second.  You may need to rearrange your array columns to make that work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint to use executemany. It seems to be exactly what I've been looking for!

I've just one "little" issue: Trying to call it using your proposal, prompts the error 
'"Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'str_' cannot be converted to a MySQL type"'

The input-array has the form 0: '0' and 1: 'test123'

Update: correction of writing mistake

Comment: Problem solved I had an issue with transforming my array into tupple form. I used  tuple([tuple(row) for row in VSA]) instead of VSA = tuple([tuple([int(row[0]), str(row[1])]) for row in VSA])